# Performant way to filter a list based on another one?

Tags: algorithm, kotlin

I need to filter the list of objects based on another.
Let's say we have two classes

```
data class Entity(val id: Long, val name: String)
data class SecondEntity(val name, val status: String)
```

I am interested in the following situation to filter the list of entities based on the status of another

```
val entityList = ...
val secondEnitityList = ...

//This how I did it
entityList.filter { entity ->
     secondEntityList.any { sEntity
        sEntity.name == entity.name && sEntity.status == "SomeStatus"
 }
}
```

Is there a more performant way to do this?

Comment: I think that looks pretty elegant to me?

Comment: but it takes O(n^2) at worth

Comment: Ah, so you're not looking for a more elegant solution, you're looking for a more *performant* solution. That's a completely different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reduce this to `O(n)` with a `HashSet`, by first filtering (based on the `status`) `secondListEntity` into a set and then using that for name lookups. So something like this:

```
val names = HashSet<String>()
secondEntityList.forEach {

    if(it.status == "SomeStatus") names.add(it.name)
}

entityList.filter { names.contains(it.name) }
```

If you have multiple lists to filter based on the same `secondEntityList` then you can reuse this set. However it's worth taking into account that constructing the set incurs an extra `O(n)` space complexity.

---

If you had multiple fields to compare, this could be extended to include a data class to hold the fields and fill the set with those, instead of strings.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to construct the set with e.g. `val names = secondEntityList.filter{ it.status == "SomeStatus" }.map{ it.name }.toSet()`?  Also worth pointing out that if you're doing many filter runs, the set can be shared, so its construction gets amortised across all runs.

Comment: Simpler yes, but not more performant which is what I took to be the most important thing here. Yes that's a good point, I'll add that in my answer.